# Get str or int from a lxml.objectify.IntElement

Tags: python, types, lxml

Hi I have a dictionary of different type values in an objectify-element and I want to get the python types out of these values.

e.g.

```
print type(deal['id'])
```

will print out

```
<type 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>
```

but I want the value like this

```
<type 'int'>
```

Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Comment: There is a hint in the documentation which says that you can get the 'python value' with .pyval
So in this case it would be: 
deal['id'].pyval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, just do `deal['id'].pytype`.

Took me a bit to get this all sorted right, since I didn't use objectify's parser, and used standard **XMLParser**.

After hours of reading the same text over and over, I see that [Objectify Help Docs](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#defining-additional-data-classes) provide all the info.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to an `int` value with: `int(deal['id'])`.